# unit testing custom role provider

Tags: c#, tdd, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm trying to exercise custom role provider methods. Each test is on its own, which means that it's indepent from other test and that in every test I create test user, test role, etc.
That's fine, I know for other approaches but this suits ok for this purpose.

So, I'm struggling with can_get_roles_for_user, here's the code

```
[Test]
public void can_get_roles_for_user()
{
    MembershipCreateStatus status = new MembershipCreateStatus();
    provider.CreateUser("testuser", "password", "testuseremail@google.com", "question", "answer", true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);
    provider.CreateUser("testuser2", "password", "testuseremail@google.com", "question", "answer", true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);

    roleProvider.CreateRole("TestRole");
    roleProvider.CreateRole("AdministratorRole");

    string[] users = { "TestUser", "TestUserAdministrator" };
    string[] roles = { "TestRole", "AdministratorTestRole" };

    roleProvider.AddUsersToRoles(users, roles);

    var user = _provider.GetUser("TestUser", false);
    string[] userRoles = _roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);

    **//WHAT SHOULD I ASSERT HERE?**

}
```

Any sugg, links to your or some other test role provider are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compare roles collections:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(roles, _roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName));
```